# Unity - set slider value if it isn't being dragged?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

Alright I have a slider in Unity whose percentage equals the current percentage of minutes in a day out of 1440, the total minutes in 24 hours.

```
 currentMinute = System.DateTime.Now.Minute + (System.DateTime.Now.Hour * 60);

            barPercentage = currentMinute / 1440;
```

This is great but I want to NOT set the slider.value to this percentage if the slider is being dragged. Ive tried everything including adding Event triggers to the handle, then triggering a bool like this:

```
 public void SliderSelected()
    {

        sliderSelect = true;
    }
    public void SliderDeselect()
    {
        sliderSelect = false;
    }
 if(!sliderSelect)
        {
           slider.value = gameController.barPercentage;
        }
```

Issue is, with this I can't drag my slider. The slider works if I delete this:

```
slider.value = gameController.barPercentage;
```

But the bool is also working- when I hold down on the handle the bool is true and false when I release since Im using PointerDown and PointerUp.

How can I do this?

Comment: As you said you tried OnPointerDown and OnPointerUp, could you post that code....?

Comment: if you are doing as mentioned in @DougJudy answer then that's fine

Comment: I needed a clarification, when users drag it manually the we can override the behaviour of script using bool value as mentioned in @DougJudy answer but the movement you leave dragging the pointer the bool value set to false and again the slider set to barPercentage ... are you expecting the same behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work fine with the following script and settings:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Slid : MonoBehaviour
{
    Slider slide;
    bool sliderSelect = false;

// Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        slide = GetComponent<Slider>();
    }

    public void SliderSelected()
    {

        sliderSelect = true;
    }

    public void SliderDeselect()
    {
        sliderSelect = false;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        float currentMinute = System.DateTime.Now.Minute + (System.DateTime.Now.Hour * 60);

        float barPercentage = currentMinute / 1440;

        if (!sliderSelect)
        {
            slide.value = barPercentage;
        }
    }
}
```

Unity inspector view of slider

[image]

Comment: There seems to be an logical error in your code.... the value that you are calculating i.e currentMinute and barPercentage always resulting zero which makes slider to set to always zero

Comment: actually you could have stayed with `var` .. it ws just a missing `f` after `1440` ;)